# Error on flask application (Invalid HTTP method)

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I have a web application that uses flask and gevent. When I run the application everything works fine regarding the endpoints, however after some time (It can be days) the following error appears:

[2023-03-13 07:26:30] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 331 0.001178
<gevent._socket3.socket at 0x7fd1707b4820 object, fd=83, family=2, type=1, proto=0>: Invalid HTTP method: '\x16\x03\x01\x01H\x01\x00\x01D\x03\x03\x0bøuð¼¡ðõ\x8d\x18\x11ö¿Ø\x1aÀr·ÇÅ\x90\x192\x11ã\x0c~kÐ®Ãª \x00\x19Þ\x158õ\x05\xadK¿\x8dEùkH¼Ñ5\x8bÈ\x1eÃÏR=MýEÍ¨\x8fó\x00b\x13\x02\x13\x03\x13\x01À,À0À+À/Ì©Ì¨\x00£\x00\x9f\x00¢\x00\x9eÌªÀ¯À\xadÀ$À(À\n'                                EùkH¼Ñ5ÈÃÏR=MýEÍ¨óbÀ,À0À+À/Ì©Ì¨£80

I don't have any endpoint named /.env.
I can't reproduce this issue since there is no logical flow as this happens ocasionally and for this specific error, happened after 3 days of app running. No one used the app during this time.
Unfortunately I don't have more details regarding this bug.

Comment: This look like a client doing an invalid HTTP request or that doesnt conform to the HTTP protocol

Comment: @Saxtheowl thank you for answering. Yes I think that the problem might be related to an invalid HTTP request, but since no one used the app during the 07:26 I found it a bit odd. I noticed something, when the app is not open on the browser there are http requests coming from the client side. Is it normal? I mean the  app is running on a server but no client is requesting data. It seems javascript is running anyway.